# can't get to work ibeacon demo app

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I'm experimenting with iBeacons and have built the *beacon-finder* [1] app on my android phone [2]. I'm able to start the app, however, I can't find the estimote iBeacon which was simulated using the estimote app on an iPhone 6S.

Any idea why it's not working?

Thank you.

[1] See https://github.com/evothings/phonegap-estimotebeacons/blob/master/examples/beacon-finder

[2] SONY XPERIA Z1 Compact, Android 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Apparantely there exists a bug, which only affects iBeacons (according to the community [1]). So it should work with the real estimote ibeacons.

However, if you wan't to fix it, **you'll need to hard code the UUID of the simulated iBeacon**. In order to do so, replace

```
app.startRangingBeacons = function()
{

    // (...)

    // Start ranging.
    estimote.beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(
        {
        }, // Empty region matches all beacons.
        onRange,
        onError);
};
```

with

```
app.startRangingBeacons = function()
{

    // (...)

    // Start ranging.
    estimote.beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(
        {
            "identifier": "MyRegion",
            "uuid": "your-actual-uuid"
        }, // Empty region matches all beacons.
        onRange,
        onError);
};
```

[1] https://github.com/evothings/phonegap-estimotebeacons/issues/78

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Estimote Android SDK which the plugin uses doesn't work with virtual beacons, only with physical estimotes.